# How do you password protect a site in progress?

Tags: password

Im wondering if there is a simple way to password protect  site thats in development using just Craft Personal?

I setup a login page and i got {% requirelogin %} to redirect but it seems with craft personal even the admin cant login via a front end login form?

Do they have to login at /admin and then jump to the front end of the site?

is there an easier way?

Comment: You don't want to use .htaccess?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Front-end user features are only available in the Pro edition of Craft.

Seems like the easiest thing to do would be to use [.htaccess password protection](http://www.htaccesstools.com/articles/password-protection/) for the site.

Comment: yea that makes sense, thought maybe there was a more integrated way but .htpassword works fine in this case

Answer (score 5):

I just released a plugin to solve this problem. No apache/nginx needed, just a simple plugin to install directly in Craft.

https://github.com/dgrigg/knockknock

Comment: Derrick are there any plans to add support for Craft 3? Would appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

I hate messing with .htaccess files across multiple environments. I also find .htaccess a bit of black magic as I don't understand regex :)

So here's my approach.

In index.php - right after the opening PHP tag - drop this in:

```
if($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] == '127.0.0.1') {

  $username = 'username';
    $password = 'password';

  if (!(isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) && ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']==$username && $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']==$password)))  {
        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="This site is protected"');
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        // Fallback message when the user presses cancel / escape
        echo 'Access denied';
      exit;
    }
}
```

Obviously replace the IP address with the server IP you want to protect and an appropriate username and password.

This will only impact things routed through index.php - you'd still be able to access static html files and such but this works for most PHP apps I've found.

Comment: if you must down vote an answer, at least give an explanation why...

Comment: Would indeed have been nice. Voted it up to get you back at 0 since this would also work for nginx.

Comment: You can also grab the IP address with `craft.request.ipAddress`

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't answer the question, but personally I don't bother; I just add a robots.txt file to stop it getting indexed.